# Setting up a Grand Jury relational database structure

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm designing a database to store information about a [grand jury](https://new-www.sjcourts.org/grandjury/previous_GJ_2012-07-12.htm). I'm wondering if my tables are normalized, and if they structure makes sense.

- A report is sent in for review by grand jury.
- Then a pdf file of their investigation is uploaded once they finish.
- The database must keep track of: Who is the roster for the year of
  the investigation, all cases for each year, and all files connected
  to each case.
- Files can be the reports themselves, attachments, final reports, and
  responses.

The Grand Jury serves as a group. There are 19 individuals per year that serve on the grand jury each year, and can not serve again for another 1 or 2 years after serving. Reports are handled as a whole by all of the grand jurors. A grand juror can be "Excused" and replaced if necessary.

[image: grand jury db]

Comment: I don't see "year" in your schema.  BTW, I'd replace "persons_id" by "person_id".